# Finding angle between two markers for use in mathematical optimisation

Tags: c#, math, geometry, computer-vision, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize the difference between sets of square markers in 3d space with a set of unknown parameters.

I have a model set of these square markers (represented by 3d position and rotation) which should at the end of optimization match up with a set of observed square markers.

I am using [Levenberg–Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm)  to optimize the set of unknown parameters, these parameters will alter the position and rotation of the model 3d markers until they match (more or less) with the observed 3d marker positions.

The observed 3d markers come from a computer vision marker detection algorithm. It gives the id of the markers seen in each frame and the transformation from the camera of each marker ([using Coplanar posit](http://www.cfar.umd.edu/~daniel/daniel_papersfordownload/CoplanarPts.pdf)). Each 'frame' would only be able to see a small number of markers in the total set of markers, there will also be inaccuracies in the transformation.

I have thought of how to construct my minimization function and I thought to try to compare the relative rotations and minimize the difference between the rotations in each iteration of the LM optimisation.

*Essentially:*

```
        foreach (Marker m1 in markers)
        {
            foreach (Marker m2 in markers)
            {
                Vector3 eulerRotation = getRotation(m1, m2);
                ObservedMarker observed1 = getMatchingObserved(m1);
                ObservedMarker observed2 = getMatchingObserved(m2);
                Vector3 eulerRotationObserved = getRotation(observed1, observed2);

                double diffX = Math.Abs(eulerRotation.X - eulerRotationObserved.X);
                double diffY = Math.Abs(eulerRotation.Y - eulerRotationObserved.Y);
                double diffZ = Math.Abs(eulerRotation.Z - eulerRotationObserved.Z);
            }
        }
```

Where diffX, diffY and diffZ are the values to be minimized.

I am using the following to calculate the angles:

```
Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(getNormal(m1), getNormal(m2));
axis.Normalize();
double angle = Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(getNormal(m1), getNormal(m2)));
Vector3 modelRotation = calculateEulerAngle(axis, angle);
```

getNormal(Marker m) calculates the normal to the plane that the square marker lies on.

I am sure I am doing something wrong here though. Throwing this all into the LM optimiser (I am using [ALGLib](http://www.alglib.net/)) doesn't seem to do anything, it goes through 1 iteration and finishes without changing any of the unknown parameters (initially all 0).

I am thinking that something is wrong with the function I am trying to minimize over. It seems sometimes the angle calculated (3rd line) returns NaN (I am currently setting this case to return diffX, diffY, diffZ as 0). Is it even valid to compare the euler angles as above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Further information:**

- Program is written in C#, I am using XNA as well.
- The model markers are represented by its four corners in 3D coords
- All the model markers are in the same coordinate space.
- Observed markers are the four corners as translations from the camera position in camera coordinate space
- If m1 and m2 markers are the same marker id or if either m1 or m2 is not observed, I set all the diffs to 0 (no difference).

Comment: Looks like you already have the answer to the question in the title.  So what is the actual question here?  It sounds like you just need to step through the code and debug it, something we cannot do for you without all of the code.

Comment: A couple of questions - (1) Does getNormal return the normal or the unit normal? (2) Does Normalize mutate the Vector3 instance or return a new instance?

Comment: Have you ever tried http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point algorithm? It is intended to solve similar problems

Comment: BlueRaja - I think the code is correct, I am not sure the technique I am using is correct however, specifically - am I going to get the similar euler angles for both the observed/model so I can compare them?

Mark M - It does the cross product of two of the edges of the square, therefore gets the normal of the plane that the square is part of.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought this might be a typo, but then I realized that this could be a bug, having been a victim of similar cases myself in the past.

Shouldn't diffY and diffZ be:

```
double diffY = Math.Abs(eulerRotation.Y - eulerRotationObserved.Y);
double diffZ = Math.Abs(eulerRotation.Z - eulerRotationObserved.Z);
```

I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment, hence posting it as an answer!

Comment: Sorry, make a mistake when copying it over, yes it should be that. It was copied of a old bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with this? Is it correct to assume that you want to minimize the "sum" of all diffs over all marker combinations? I think if you want to use LM you should not use `Math.Abs`.

One alternative would be to formulate your objective function manually and use another optimizer. I have recently ported two non-linear optimizers to C# which do not even require you to compute derivatives:

- [COBYLA2](https://github.com/cureos/cscobyla), supports non-linear constraints but require more iterations.
- [BOBYQA](https://github.com/cureos/csbobyqa), limited to variable bounds constraints, but provides a considerable more efficient iteration scheme.